# What is the need of main thread in Android?

Tags: android

i know that the android app runs in the main thread means UI thread.I want to know what is need of main thread to run an app? What happens if we do not use the main thread to run app.Why main thread is necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/A_Basic_Overview_of_Android_Threads_and_Thread_handlers):

**What is the need of main thread?**

> When an Android application is first started, the runtime system creates a single thread in which all application components will run by default. This thread is generally referred to as the main thread. The primary role of the main thread is to handle the user interface in terms of event handling and interaction with views in the user interface. Any additional components that are started within the application will, by default, also run on the main thread.

**Why is main thread necessary?**

> Any component within an application that performs a time-consuming task using the main thread will cause the entire application to appear to lock up until the task is completed. This will typically result in the operating system displaying an “Application is unresponsive” warning to the user. Clearly, this is far from the desired behavior for any application. In such a situation, this can be avoided simply by launching the task to be performed in a separate thread, allowing the main thread to continue unhindered with other tasks.

Please refer to the link to understand more about main thread with an example.

For more details, you can follow [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html).

Answer (score 3):

Well it needs a thread.  Every app ever written has at least one-  even the simplest Hello World app in the simplest language.  A thread is just a series of instructions being run on the processor.  So even if your app doesn't multithread at all, the one series of instructions it is running would be a thread-  you could even call it the main thread if you wanted.  So it would literally be impossible to have no main thread at all.

What makes the main thread special in Android is that you're only allowed to change visible elements on it.  If Android didn't have that restriction, you'd have the possibility of race conditions and inconsistent UIs-  the possibility that views are being changed on one thread while another is drawing to the screen.  To prevent this you'd need to do a lot of manual locking.  Instead, Android decided to only allow these changes on the main thread.  That prevents a large class of timing bugs and race conditions (although not all, depending on how you implement your models).